# Lumen unit test post request

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I'm having trouble setting up a unit test in which I receive a POST request in the API.
I have a relationship on the table that should link to the user who created the POST request. And in the API I link the correct user like this:
`$record->user()->associate($req->user());`

It works great, but I can't seem to write a unit test that works.

My unit test looks like this

```
$user = factory('App\User')->create();
$item = factory('App\Item')->create();
$response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->post('/route', $item);

$this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the result of the test? Btw, I don't think this is a unit test, looks more like a functional test.

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` It fails on user id in the database

Comment: Add the test result to your question. Also would be useful is you show the result of `dd($req->user())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created the item in the database before making the API call.

`$item = factory('App\Item')->create();` 
should have been `$item = factory('App\Item')->make();` 
and 
`$response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->post('/route', $item);`
should have been `$response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->post('/route', $item->toArray());`